# Need to execute SQL query in AutoIt

Tags: sql-server, autoit

I want to do database operations in AutoIt. I written some code for it, but it is not working:

```
Global $adCN

$adCN = ObjCreate ("ADODB.Connection") ; <== Create SQL connection
$adCN.Open ("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=sqlstaging;DATABASE=NivioAsia2;uid=niviodbstaging;pwd=niviodbstaging;") ; <== Connect with required credentials

if @error Then
    MsgBox(0, "ERROR", "Failed to connect to the database")
    Exit
Else
    MsgBox(0, "Success!", "Connection to database successful!")
EndIf

$sQuery = "select * from irws_m_users where n_userid=10318583224314"

$adCN.Execute($sQuery)

$adCN.Close ; ==> Close the database

Exit
```

How can I get data from table using [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done now...

```
$constrim="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=sqlstaging;DATABASE=NivioAsia2;uid=niviodbstaging;pwd=niviodbstaging;"
$adCN = ObjCreate ("ADODB.Connection") ; <== Create SQL connection
$adCN.Open ($constrim) ; <== Connect with required credentials
MsgBox(0,"",$constrim )

if @error Then
    MsgBox(0, "ERROR", "Failed to connect to the database")
    Exit
Else
    MsgBox(0, "Success!", "Connection to database successful!")
EndIf

$sQuery = "select * from irws_m_users where n_userid=10318583224314"

$result = $adCN.Execute($sQuery)
MsgBox(0, "", $result.Fields( "s_username" ).Value)
$adCN.Close ; ==> Close the database
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted this code without changing any values and I received message in AutoIt "Connection to database successful!". How come?

Comment: @maniootek The problem is the `MessageBox` before the if. Every function call clears `@error`, and since the MessageBox succeeds, @error is 0.